# How to add listener name to the SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. I'll appreciate it if someone helps me modify the below query that will show the listener name as another column in the output.

```
select 
    tr.replica_server_name as ReplicaServerName, 
    trs.role_desc as ReplicaRole
from 
    sys.availability_replicas ar
inner join 
    sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states trs on trs.replica_id = tr.replica_id
where 
    tr.replica_server_name = @@servername
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join on [`sys.availability_group_listeners`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-availability-group-listeners-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```sql
select 
    tr.replica_server_name as ReplicaServerName, 
    trs.role_desc as ReplicaRole,
    agl.dns_name as ListenerName
from 
    sys.availability_replicas ar
inner join 
    sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states trs on trs.replica_id = tr.replica_id
left join
    sys.availability_group_listeners agl on agl.group_id = ar.group_id
where
    ar.replica_server_name = @@servername;
```

Comment: Getting error . The multi-part identifier "tr.replica_id" could not be bound.

Comment: I literally copy-pastad that out of your question. Should be `ar.`